# How can I move image with the help of accelerometer iphone xcode?

Tags: iphone

I am working on xcode4.1 not in coca 2d. I want to handle image through accelerometer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display it. Use the [center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) property to move it on the screen.

Use the [UIAccelerometerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html) to get the move of the phone.